# Jmeter: Pull paths from file at random

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am building a load/stress test for some webpages. I have a HTTP Request Default set up that has the base server name. I would like to use a Random Controller and HTTP Request to check all pages at random, but I do not want to have to make 150 HTTP Request that each hold a unique path. I would rather have one HTTP request that pulls a path at random from a file.

Is what I am describing possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-worded my searching and have found that this is not possible. I think I am going to take the advice from another forum and randomize my file to achieve this. Seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's possible. Everything is possible. In case of JMeter you'll need to do some scripting.

Given the following test plan structure:

- setUp Thread Group

  - Beanshell Sampler

    ```
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    List lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/your/file"));
    bsh.shared.lines = lines;
    ```
- Thread Group

  - HTTP Request Sampler, Path: `${randomline}`

    - Beanshell PreProcessor

      ```
      List lines = bsh.shared.lines;
      Random rnd = new Random();
      vars.put("randomline", lines.get(rnd.nextInt(lines.size())));
      ```

It will be possible to use random URL from file as HTTP Request Path.

Explanation:

- [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) - special Thread Group type which is executed before any other Thread Group. The idea is to read file only once.
- [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) - uses [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) library to read all the lines into lines array and [bsh.shared](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) namespace so the array will be accessible globally to all Thread Groups
- [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) - uses [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random line number, obtains random value from the lines array and stores the value into `randomline` variable via [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class.

Refer generated random line as `${randomline}` where required.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.